# (C#) make auto GC possible for Dictionary<ReaderWriterLockSlim>

Tags: c#, thread-safety, readerwriterlockslim, readerwriterlock

I maintained a dictionary of ReaderWriterLockSlim objects for resource access:(sample code is ugly here, just makes you understand my purpose)

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ReaderWriterLockSlim> rwResourceLocks =
                                new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ReaderWriterLockSlim>();
```

And use like this:

```
if (ResourceStore.Exist("resourceID")) {
    if (rwResourceLocks["resourceID"] == null) {
        /* create a new lock in thread-safe way */
    }
    rwResourceLocks["resourceID"].EnderReadLock();
    var rc = ResourceStore.GetResource("resourceID");
    /* further use of rc... */
    rwResourceLocks["resourceID"].ExitReadLock();    
}
```

Resources may be added or removed dynamically and their life-cycle is unpredictable (unable to mornitor removal of resource), as amount of resources grows up, size of rwResourceLocks is increasing too which will lead to memory trouble. Is there a way to solve this problem? (Obviously I can't simply call rwResourceLocks.Clear() to do this)

I know it's a bit complicated :(

Comment: There is a race condition: if 2 threads are checking for same non-existing `resourceID`, then they both may try to create new lock. Hopefully it's not a problem or you are aware about it. It's not clear why you need locks to access resources. You may speed up access by implementing a cache (if that was an aim). Otherwise without knowing if resource is in use or not is it ok to free it? If yes, then cache again. Store last access time for each resource, check (periodically or when adding new resource) for it, free when expired.

Comment: coz those resources are not only for read, but get modified sometimes, i'll hold a write lock to prevent from reading it at that time. (e.g a file resource)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a [ConditionalWeakTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx). A `ConditionalWeakTable` automatically removes a value from the dictionary when its key has been collected by the Garbage Collector.

```
ConditionalWeakTable<object, ReaderWriterLockSlim> _locks;

if (ResourceStore.Exists("resourceID")) {
    var rc = ResourceStore.GetResource("resourceID");
    var lck = _locks.GetValue(rc, () => new ReaderWriterLockSlim());

    lck.EnterReadLock();

    // Use the resource here

    lck.ExitReadLock();
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! BTW I have a question, for some none-reference resource like cached integer value, or string content(so Key of WeakTable is not an object), does it still work ? @Wazner

Comment: No, ConditionalWeakTable requires its key to be a reference type (Which an integer isn't). And even though a string is a reference type, it is not recommended because their lifetime are hard to predict because of [string interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) in .NET